# CSS-transformed inline SVG not triggering event handler in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, svg, transform

Events attached to an inline SVG's polygon and text elements do not always trigger once that SVG has been transformed with CSS under Chrome.

```
<script>
$(function() {
$('polygon, text').on('click', function(e) {
    $('#text').html(Math.random());
});
});
</script>

<style>
svg {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
#test1 svg {
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(30deg) rotateY(-35deg) rotateX(45deg);
    transform: rotateZ(30deg) rotateY(-35deg) rotateX(45deg);
}
</style>
```

See complete fiddle reproducing the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/qLCV3/

Try clicking anywhere on the SVG. Any click should update the random number at the top of the page, but it doesn't always under Chrome.

It works fine under Firefox.
Is this a Chrome related issue? Is this something I can fix?

Comment: I've seen similar bugs before. Try to do your transforms in the SVG.

Comment: Reported now as https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=316093

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue. I've made a simpler test case here: http://jsfiddle.net/qLCV3/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround suggested by Michael Mulanny: apply the transform in the SVG.

```
$('g').attr('transform', 'translate(250, 0) scale(1, .58) rotate(45)');
```

... where 250 is 50% of the SVG's width.

The transforms are not the same (there is no rotateX, rotateY or rotateZ for SVG) but the result looks identical.

Thanks for reporting the bug.